# PHP for loop query

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, counter

I have the following:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['itemCode']); $i++) {

        $body .= '<tr>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;"><b>' . $i . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemCode'][$i]) . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemDesc'][$i]) . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:center;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemQty'][$i]) . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['itemPrice'][$i] . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['itemLineTotal'][$i] . '</td>';
        $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['resale'][$i] . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['difference'][$i] . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">-€' . $_POST['discount'][$i] . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '</tr>';
    }
```

I wish to start the counter ($i) at one and I have tied everything but noting works can anyone help?

Comment: Do you actually want to skip the first element of the array, or do you just want to display the counter starting from 1?

Comment: @Barmar - just start at 1 no I need all items to displayed

Comment: Arrays start at 0, so if you start at 1 you'll skip the first element.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

If you assgin `$i` to 1 you have to add `=` like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($_POST['itemCode']); $i++) {

        $body .= '<tr>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;"><b>' . $i . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemCode'][($i-1)]) . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemDesc'][($i-1)]) . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:center;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemQty'][($i-1)]) . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['itemPrice'][($i-1)] . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['itemLineTotal'][($i-1)] . '</td>';
        $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['resale'][($i-1)] . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['difference'][($i-1)] . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">-€' . $_POST['discount'][($i-1)] . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '</tr>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the work:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['itemCode']); $i++) {
        $body .= '<tr>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;"><b>' . $i+1 . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemCode'][$i]) . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemDesc'][$i]) . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:center;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemQty'][$i]) . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['itemPrice'][$i] . '</td>';
        $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['itemLineTotal'][$i] . '</td>';
        $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['resale'][$i] . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['difference'][$i] . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">-€' . $_POST['discount'][$i] . '</b></td>';
        $body .= '</tr>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to @Rizier123 I have stumbled the answer:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($_POST['itemCode']); $i++) {

    $body .= '<tr>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;"><b>' . ($i) . '</b></td>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemCode'][($i-1)]) . '</td>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemDesc'][($i-1)]) . '</td>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:center;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemQty'][($i-1)]) . '</td>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['itemPrice'][($i-1)] . '</td>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['itemLineTotal'][($i-1)] . '</td>';
    $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['resale'][($i-1)] . '</b></td>';
    $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['difference'][($i-1)] . '</b></td>';
    $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">-€' . $_POST['discount'][($i-1)] . '</b></td>';
    $body .= '</tr>';
}
```

Notice @Rizier123 - that I took out the "-" - works great.  Many thanks to you all

Answer (score -1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($_POST['itemCode']); $i++) {
    $body .= '<tr>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;"><b>' . $i . '</b></td>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;">' .    htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemCode'][$i]) . '</td>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemDesc'][$i]) . '</td>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:center;">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['itemQty'][$i]) . '</td>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['itemPrice'][$i] . '</td>';
    $body .= '<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['itemLineTotal'][$i] . '</td>';
    $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['resale'][$i] . '</b></td>';
    $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">€' . $_POST['difference'][$i] . '</b></td>';
    $body .= '<b><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; background: #fff1f1; color:#640b0b; text-align:right;">-€' . $_POST['discount'][$i] . '</b></td>';
    $body .= '</tr>';
}
```